# C++ Dll import function to VB

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I have a dll import from a header file:

```
  Long APIENTRY GetPrinterPortNum(Char *portArray, int size);
```

what is the correct conversion to Visual Basic?

Comment: You can use Declare keyword -> check doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/declare-statement

Comment: I am not sure about the types

Comment: I think that portArray should be String, size should be Integer and the return type Long.

Comment: "portArray" is pretty misleading, the function name suggests you need to pass the printer name.  Which however doesn't explain why you have to pass a *size*.  Only somewhat logical (and safe) conclusion is that it does both, return both a port number as the return value and the name copied into the portArray buffer.  So StringBuilder as the 1st argument, Integer as the second, Integer as the return value (not Long).  Call with a StringBuilder whose Capacity is set high enough, pass that capacity as the 2nd arg.  A negative return value would typically indicate an error.